# Leavers Script-AD

Tags: csv, powershell

I'm trying to formulate a way I can automate removal of AD Groups from disabled users OU in AD.

I would like for the script to have an exception to only remove certain domain services folder addresses starting with ****.

Also, for it to remove all bar two exceptions to this.

I would be happy for this to be done via csv file or just through the AD OU.

We also have a system that holds onto users even after they are deleted from AD.

We normally have to go to to web address linked to the server and manually terminate the user

Any help appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: A "domain services folder address"? Do you mean certain containers/OU's?

Comment: Do you have any code? Have you looked at the available AD cmdlets? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617195.aspx